# Why are new Mongo Collections not available in mLab after Heroku push? MERN stack

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, mern

I had previously deployed to Heroku with collection A in my dbMain. This worked great and I was able to perform CRUD operations with my deployed app to this collection.

However I continued developing my app and added collections B and C to dbMain. Locally, everything works like a charm, however when I push my work to Heroku, I check `mLab` and collections B and C are not created.

When I try to add something to either B or C with the deployed app I get this error:

> Failed to load resource:
>   the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Because B and C are missing, I assume that those are the failed loads?

I've looked at the Network Inspector in the the dev tools and managed to understand that the there is a valid payload, I can still write and send payloads to Collection A. But I just cant seem to figure out why B and C don't get created with the push? Am I missing a step?

I'm really new to this material and would appreciate your time and help.